# Send message from PHP script to a PHP ratchet websocket server without ZMQ or any PECL packages

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

**CONTEXT**

I am using RatchetPHP to let my HTML clients to be in sync with themselves.

**websocket-server.php**

I run this file using `php websocket-server.php`, which loops indefinitively to handle websocket connections and messages.

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

use Me\Server;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Server()
        )
    ),
    8000
);

$server->run();
```

**client.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var conn = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000");

            conn.onopen = function(e) {
                console.log("Connection established!");

                setTimeout(function() {
                    conn.send("coucou");
                }, 5000);
            };

            conn.onmessage = function(e) {
                console.log(e.data);
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Me\Server.php**

This is the Server that handles events (messages, connections).

```
namespace Me;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use SplObjectStorage;

class Server implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

**ATTEMPT**

I also need my back-end to send messages to the socket server that will himself send a message to all the connected clients. This is a Laravel back-end that for example will send a message to clients to inform that a new user record is available and they should reload their web page. Here is my attempt:

**send.php**

```
$address="127.0.0.1";
$port="8000";
$msg="new user available";

$sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) or die("Cannot create a socket");

socket_connect($sock,$address,$port) or die("Could not connect to the socket");
$result = socket_write($sock,$msg);

socket_close($sock);
```

What I noticed is that Ratchet is parsing HTTP messages, so if I understand right I need to send an HTTP message instead of a plain messages (I confirmed it, because if I print the raw message before it being parsed in the file `vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/Http/HttpServer.php` at the begining of the method `onMessage`, I can see my message, but then the check `if (true !== $from->httpHeadersReceived) {` does not pass because I am sending a raw text).

**QUESTION**

How can I send an HTTP message to a web socket server without any dependencies like ReactZMQ and some PECL packages?

Comment: Hi @Anwar. Did you manage to solve your problem? I'm very new Ratchet, and I pretty much need to do the same thing: using WebSocket to push data from server to clients any time new records are available.